# Return Parameter If in Child Table Meet Some Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, return-value

I have table like this

Parent table

```
id, column1,  etc
-    -         -     
-    -         -
```

Detail

```
id, parent_id, column1, actual_finish (value is true/false)
 -     -            -           -      
 -     -            -           -
```

I want to check if all column `actual_finish` have value true, then return 1 (I think this will be return parameter), else return 0.

For example

parent

```
id   column1  etc,
------------------
1    value1    a
```

Detail

```
id, parent_id, column1, actual_finish (value is true/false)
------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         a           true
2       1         b           false
```

This will return 0, because second row actual finish value is false, but if second row column actual_finish updated to true, then return 1

I want to create a stored procedure that returns 0 or 1 based on column `actual_finish` in the `detail` table.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What should the spc return if there are no rows at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using,

```
select min(case when actual_finish='true' then 1 else 0 end) from tab_Detail where parent_id=1;
```

SP, something like..

```
create procedure getStatusById
(@id int)
as
begin
declare @res as int=0
set @res=(select min(case when actual_finish='true' then 1 else 0 end) from tab_Detail
where parent_id=@id);
return @res
print(@res)
end
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ac61ce8ddd0ff0bfd5c42c1f8a3b636)

Answer (score 0):

Query you could use is

```
Select returnvalue= case when totalCount=trueCount then 1 else 0 end 
from
(select 
    trueCount=count (case when actual_finish ='true' then 1 else 0 end), 
    totalCount = count(1)
from
parent p left join detail d
    on p.id=d.parent_id
group by p.id
)T
```

This is assuming that you return false if there is no row in detail table for parent id

Comment: can you explain me about this line

    totalCount = count(1)

Answer (score 0):

I think requirement is,even one row exists where actual_fnish is false then return 0.

```
declare @res as int=1
If exists(select 1 from dbo.tbldetail where actual_finish='false')
set @res=0
```

`actual_finish` should be `BIT` data type (0 or 1)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`.  To handle multiple rows in `parents`:

```
select p.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from details d
                          where d.parent_id = p.id and
                                d.actual_finish = 'false'
                         )
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from parents p;
```